# .. "bone-dry-bed of reality" lexical meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "bone-dry bed of reality" mean? Is that a set expression or there are even more than one embedded? 
In [Urbandictionary.com](http://Urbandictionary.com) I found that "bone-dry" is "mundane" but the rest remains unclear.

The context surrounding it: "

And let's not forget that the CIA isn't the only organization with questionable people on its payroll. Since the beginning of the war, NATO has been bribing drug smugglers to let fuel pass through the Khyber Pass from Pakistan into Afghanistan. NATO payments, thousands of dollars for each truck, have to dwarf anything the CIA is giving to Ahmed Wali Karzai.

You can take it to the bank that the CIA knows all of this, just as it knew in the early '60s that Diem's brother was a corrupt thug. You can also be certain that the CIA would prefer to have untainted sources. But the **bone-dry bed of reality** in Afghanistan is that there are few if any to be had. In that country, you survive by renting clans, tribes and narcotics dealers, which comes with their unsavory business whether you like it or not.

"

The source: [**TIME Why the CIA Can't Be Picky About Afghan Partners**
by **Robert Baer**](http://content.time.com/time/world/article/0,8599,1932967,00.html)

[image: the screenshot of Time article and the phrase which needs explanation]

Comment: While driving, try adjusting your car seat forward while gently pressing on the brakes. Your forehead will experience the bone-dry bed of reality that is the steering wheel.  **Do Not Try This.  It Hurts!**

Comment: Thank you for your example. So, turning back to reality the meaning would be?

Comment: It's a metaphor. Also the metaphor is appropriate for Afghanistan because it is very dry there.

Comment: Loronzo, why did you not post what you thought that might mean, and why you doubted that?

Although in 60 years I've never seen, heard or otherwise come across anything remotely like "the bone-dry bed of reality" I do think it wholly reasonable  to assume it means "in (strongly emphasised) reality."

Why would you doubt that, please?

Comment: After some researh and tutorial with one native speaker (a British guy, who also teaches English as a second language abroad) this is how I understand it (and will be partially citing him): Nearly everyone in Afghanistan is involved in disreputable business and that's the mundane reality and it's as empty as in desert to look for something else or better. 

"It's a 'cold truth', 'harsh reality', it's completely clear that this is the only option." my English friend says.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the expression may be alluding not to a bed to sleep in but to a riverbed, which in desert regions may become bone-dry during the dry season. Nevertheless, the phrase "the bed of reality is that..." is not a widely established catch-phrase (or metaphor), and the syntax of that part of the sentence is not especially good: most people wouldn't say "the bed is that..." and "the bed of reality" is still ultimately a bed. A less florid writer might have said "the bone-dry reality is that...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two expressions in one phrase:

**bone dry**  [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bone_dry)

> Completely or extremely dry.

bed (support) of reality (stark)

Thus the **bed of reality** is bone dry ... empty, no other options, stark truth.

As in:

> But - the bottom line/fact is - in Afghanistan there are no
>   untainted sources to be had.